# Automatically Change Validation Entries When the Source of Validation List Changes (Google Sheets)

Tags: vba, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi there I have a vba code on my regular excel sheet that works well. I want something that makes the job done on google sheets.

Let me explain what this code does:

So basically, whenever you use a drop down on your sheet, this macro instantly changes the selection you made into a formula that has the same result.

If you ever go and change the value of the choice in the original list, all the cells that currently resolve to that same value "position" will update automatically since they're all formulas.

So can anyone help me to make the same in Google Sheets?

This is a simple gif that show how the vba code works

http://g.recordit.co/DfFslr0iJF.gif

This is the sample file if you guys want to take a look at

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8OCuWHp5L8TWDFyR0xDV1d0bTA/view?usp=sharing

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strValidationList As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim lngNum As Long

On Error GoTo Nevermind
strValidationList = Mid(Target.Validation.Formula1, 2)
strVal = Target.Value
lngNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strVal, Range(strValidationList), 0)

If strVal <> "" And lngNum > 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Formula = "=INDEX(" & strValidationList & ", " & lngNum & ")"
End If

Nevermind:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the onEdit() trigger. The code below gets the context of the edit by examining the event object passed to the function and dynamically rebuilds validation rule for the target range (in this case, 'A1'). As in your example, the list values reside in column 2:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var listValuesCol = 2;

  if(range.getColumn() == listValuesCol && sheet.getName() =='yourSheetName'){ // checking if the values were updated

    var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(1, listValuesCol, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); //range containing validation rule list values
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(1,1); //target cell, e.g. A1

    var newValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true) //boolean flag for showing or disabling dropdown list
    .build();

    targetRange.setDataValidation(newValidationRule);

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();


  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anton. As you explained it seems like it is gonna work the way I wanted but still I'm getting and error on the 3rd line "TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined." 

How can I resolve that? 

Also I'm planning to add many dropdowns inside the sheet. So is there a short way to apply this script to all of the dropdowns inside my sheet.
Cheers,

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place to get ad hoc solutions tailored to your specific situation. You should probably get yourself familiar with Google Apps Script documentation first https://developers.google.com/apps-script/  The argument of the function ('e') is the event object generated from the spreadsheet itself. So don't expect it to work, unless you actually type values in your spreadsheet. onEdit() is basically an event handler, so if you execute the function manually, 'e' will of course be 'undefined'

Comment: Thanks Anton, I dig around for how to use the triggers, I managed to get rid of errors but the code is not working as I expected. I gave a permission to edit this sheet for this link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztE_yVkM-bIzQ8y5xuBw9zUxme7Q90FjTPur3fpqbJM/edit?usp=sharing If you can help me out I would aprreciate it. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Have you tried running the onEdit() function from the Script Editor at least once? The permissions screen should pop up prompting you to allow the script to manage your data. I copied your spreadsheet and everything worked perfectly for me (though I had to disconnect the library)

Comment: Hi Anton of course I run the script from the script editor and gave the permission for authorization. However I couldn't get the result :/ I'll try again hope I'll get the result :/

Comment: Could it be interfering with the code in the library connected to the spreadsheet? Try disconnecting it temporarily and running the script. Also, I noticed that, for some reason, you defined the range variable like this getRange("b1:b5"), which doesn't make much sense as you are limiting the range to just 5 rows. Not sure what you need it for